# Showing Wrong User Data CakePHP

Tags: authentication, cakephp

I'm simply want to show the user that is currently logged in. My code for the Auth section came from 2.x cookbook.

The issue is the following:

I have 2 users currently in the system. User A and User B. User B was created second. Instead of showing the current user, it just shows User B. I assume it is because User B was the last to be created, because if I create User C, it will show user C instead.

Here is my action:

```
public function index($id = null) {
    $this->set('strains', $this->Strain->find('all'));

    $this->loadModel('User');
    $users = $this->User->find('all');
    $this->set('users', $users);

    $this->set('userDataName', $this->Auth->user('id'));

    if($this->Auth->user()) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        $user = $this->Session->write('user', $this->User->findById($id));
        $this->set('user', $user);
    }
}
```

Here is the line in my view that should show the current user:

```
<?php echo $user['User']['username']; ?>
```

I've read several stack questions, but none seem to go over this specific scenario. I'm open to completely re-writing code if necessary. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It's a logic error

> Here is the line in my view that should show the current user:
>
> ```
> <?php echo $user['User']['username']; ?>
> ```

In the template the username is taken from the `$user` variable.

> ```
> public function index($id = null) {
>         ...
>         $this->User->id = $id;
>         $user = $this->Session->write('user', $this->User->findById($id));
>         $this->set('user', $user);
>      }
> }
> ```

The user variable depends on the `$id` parameter, not directly the currently logged-in user.

### How to access the logged in user data

The simplest way to [access the logged in user data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user) is to use `AuthComponent::user` i.e. in  a template:

```
<?php echo AuthComponent::user('username'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way to display the username of the current session user is to use the auth component:

```
in controller
$user = $this->Auth->user(); // returns array with user data or null
$this->set('user', $user);

in view
echo $user['username'];
```

Comment: Why don't I need to put echo $user['User']['username']? Does it already know I'm accessing that array?